# Anonymous Function which returns different types C++

Tags: c++, function

I want to create an anonymous function which takes in an int and a set as parameters, and either modify the set (be a void) or return false based on the int. Is it possible to do?

Code is here. You can see the repetitive if statements which bother me.

```
bool sudoku2(std::vector<std::vector<char>> grid) {
        std::set<char> row, col, block;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++) {
                for (std::size_t j = 0; j < grid[i].size(); j++) {
                        if (grid[i][j] != '.') {
                                if (row.find(grid[i][j]) == row.end()) {
                                        row.insert(grid[i][j]);
                                } else {
                                        return false;
                                }
                        }
                        if (grid[j][i] != '.') {
                                if (col.find(grid[j][i]) == col.end()) {
                                        col.insert(grid[j][i]);
                                } else {
                                        return false;
                                }
                        }
                        if (grid[i/3*3 + j/3][i%3*3 + j%3] != '.') {
                                if (block.find(grid[i/3*3 + j/3][i%3*3 + j%3]) == block.end()) {
                                        block.insert(grid[i/3*3 + j/3][i%3*3 + j%3]);
                                } else {
                                        return false;
                                }
                        }
                }
                row.clear();
                col.clear();
                block.clear();
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Why not just always have it return bool and ignore the return value when appropriate?

Comment: Sure. Use a C++17 compiler and have your function return a `std::variant<std::monostate, bool>`, or `std::optional<bool>`, with a slightly older compiler. Otherwise, have your function return a short `struct` that implement somethings that's logically equivalent to this.